# css coding on Myspace - Problem

Tags: css, myspace

Hey Folks. I've read what I could, and I'm certainly no master, but I'm fixing up a colleagues profile on myspace.com, and im working with 2 divs in each side of the screen, and I want them to align so that they are next to each other. I've tried float: left; and float: right;, and I've tried margin: right; on div 1 and such.

Could you help?

Here's the site:
http://www.myspace.com/jonasjohansen

**This is info for div1:**

```
    <div class="textBox" align="left" style="width: 290px; float: left;
 word-wrap:break-word">  
        <span class="orangetext15">
        BANDS
        </span>

        <b>MOVE</b><br />
        Fredrik ....balbalbalbla
        </div>

        <style>
    .textBox {
    position: relative;
    left:-320px;
    top:-120px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;

        }
        </style>
```

**This is info for div2:**

```
<style>.i {display:none;}{!-eliminate bio header!-}table table td.text table td.text {display:none;}{!-recover in shows and friends-!}table table td.text div table td.text,table table td.text table.friendSpace td.text {display:inline;}{! move up our custom section.  You may change px value !}div.myDivR {position:relative; top:0px; margin-bottom:-300px; }{! you can apply style to the custom div !}div.myDivR {background-color:white; border:2px solid; border-color:darkgreen; float: right;}</style></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><span class="off">Re-Open Bio Table give it our own Class </span><table class="myBio" style="width:435px;"><tr><i class="i"></i><td class="myBioHead" valign="center" align="left" width="auto" bgcolor="ffcc99" height="17">  &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="orangetext15"> ABOUT JONAS JOHANSEN</span>  </td></tr><tr><td><table class="myBioI"><tr><td><span class="off"></span>


blalbalbalbalbla

<span class="off">END Bio Content </span>
```

Comment: It looks fine to me, while using Chrome. What browser are you using to check your code?

Comment: in IE8, All text in his biography is pulled to the right. Very difficult to explain, so here's a picture. http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/332/wdaw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is coming from the fact that you have the Bands section (which appears to belong in the left column of the layout) in a `td` element that is on the right side of the layout.  When you apply your `float: left;` to the Bands `td`, it floats it all the way over to the left column (through the eccentricities of browser rendering), but it leaves space for the Band `td` in the right column.

Can you move the Band `td` in the code for the page?  I am unfamiliar with what is editable in Myspace, so I'm not sure, but that should easily fix the problem you're having.